# PHP - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm trying to iterate through an object property called `items` that contains an array:

```
foreach ($this->footerList->items as $item)
```

When I execute the statement, I get an error saying - "Trying to get property of non-object" even though

```
var_dump($this->footerList)
```

shows that `$this->footerList` does indeed contain an `items` array.

```
object(FooterModel)#13 (1) 
{ 
    ["items"]=> array(3) 
    { 
        [0]=> array(5) 
        { 
             ["id"]=> string(20) "terms-and-conditions" 
             ["title"]=> string(20) "Terms and Conditions" 
             ["url"]=> string(23) "home/termsandconditions" 
             ["label"]=> string(20) "Terms and Conditions" 
             ["authenticatedOnly"]=> string(5) "false" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(5) 
        { 
             ["id"]=> string(14) "privacy-policy" 
             ["title"]=> string(14) "Privacy Policy" 
             ["url"]=> string(18) "home/privacypolicy" 
             ["label"]=> string(14) "Privacy Policy" 
             ["authenticatedOnly"]=> string(5) "false" 
         } 
    } 
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out why the loop statement can't resolve the `$this->footerList->items`?

Comment: Please show more code, what does `var_dump($this->footerList->items);` say?

Comment: Make sure you called `var_dump` at the same scope of your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
foreach ($this->footerList["items"] as $item)
```

Comment: if `$this->footerList` is `object(FooterModel)` why do you need to do this?

Comment: $this->footerList is an array, not an object — hence "non-object".

Comment: If `$this->footerList` is an array, then `var_dump($this->footerList)` will echo `array(1){...}` not `object(FooterModel)`

Comment: It's an object with an `items` array as a property, as a [simple example](http://viper-7.com/IZiQvR) will show you.

Answer (score 0):

This is most commonly seen when you are trying to use `$this` and not inside of a class, your are trying to reference an array as an object or within a static method.

You will need to provide some more code to get a clearer answer.

**Update**

I formatted your output.

```
foreach ( (object) $this->footerList->items as $item)
```

The above will cast all your subarrays to objects to allow you to use your code the way your planned it.